# Update by the newest value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have `salesperson´s` in `TableTap` and i need to udpate these into `TableNim` per `item`. `TableTap` has a date `tap_Date` and i need to get the newest occurence of `salesperson`. `Item` is a unique value in `TableNim`.

```
TableTap
| salesperson   | item  | tap_Date
|---------------|-------|-----------
| person1       | item1 | 2020-01-20
| person1       | item1 | 2020-01-21
| person1       | item2 | 2020-01-22
| person2       | item2 | 2020-01-22
| person2       | item3 | 2020-01-23
```

Result should be:

```
TableNim
| salesperson   | item  |
|---------------|-------|
| person1       | item1 |
| person2       | item2 |
| person2       | item3 |
```

I've tried the following

```
UPDATE TableNim SET TableNim.myyja =
(SELECT TOP 1 salesperson FROM TableTap
WHERE spec = 1 
and salespersons > '' 
and customer > ''
ORDER BY tap_Date DESC)
FROM TableNim, TableTap
WHERE
TableTap.item = TableNim.item
```

The result of the query ends up to have just one same salesperson in every row. 
Any help?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Comment: Yeah, MS SQL Sever

Comment: Slight detour...but ANSI-92 style joins have been around now for almost 30 years. Time to update your syntax. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
update tablenim 
   set salesperson=b2.salesperson
  from (select row_number() over(partition by item order by tap_date desc) as rnk
              ,salesperson
              ,item 
          from tabletap
        ) b2
  join tablenim b 
    on b.item=b2.item
   and b2.rnk=1
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple method is a correlated subquery or `cross apply`:

```
update n
    set item = t.item
    from TableNim n cross apply
         (select top (1) t.*
          from TableTap t
          where t.salesperson = n.salesperson
          order by tap_date desc
         ) t;
```

With an index on `TableTab(salesperson, tap_date desc, item)`, this often performs better than window functions.